# New USB-C charger to be used on an old MagSafe2 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

**Are there any adaptors so I can use the new MacBook Pro USB-C Charger in my old Magsafe 2 MacBook Pro?**

I know one day I am going to buy the new MacBook Pro and my old original charger broke on a trip, so I want to buy the new one as I use two chargers, one lives in my traveling bag and the other stays home.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no adapter that goes from USB-C to Magsafe 2.**  Though there is a [project to create turn a USB-C into a MagSafe adapter](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3138865/computer-hardware/start-up-creates-usb-c-to-magsafe-adapter-for-new-macbook-and-other-devices.html)

Tech accessories usually don't go backwards and it's usually because the old accessories don't have the capability to communicate properly with the new devices (i.e. voltage negotiation with USB-C charging).

Unfortunately, you will have to get an older charger to support that MacBook Pro.